# how to use `ecto.Multi delete` and avoid error when the query get_by return nil?

Tags: elixir, ecto

My original code is as follows:

```
from(p in Mirror.Imports.Picture,
  where: p.picture_name in ^picture_name_list
)
|> Repo.delete_all()

case Repo.get_by(Mirror.Imports.Product, num_id: num_id) do
  nil -> #
    :ok

  value ->
    Repo.delete(value)
    :ok
end
```

And I want to use Multi, and rewrite it as follows:

```
Ecto.Multi.new()
|> Ecto.Multi.delete_all(:delete_all,from(p in Mirror.Imports.Picture,
where: p.picture_name in ^picture_name_list))
|> Ecto.Multi.delete(:delete,  Repo.get_by(Mirror.Imports.Product, num_id: num_id))
```

But the new version will error get Repo.get_by return nil?

The error message is as follows:

```
== Compilation error in file mirror_a.exs ==
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Multi.delete/4    
    
    The following arguments were given to Ecto.Multi.delete/4:
    
        # 1
        %Ecto.Multi{operations: [delete_all: {:delete_all, #Ecto.Query<from p0 in Mirror.Imports.Picture, where: p0.picture_name in ^["07258eb714o1cn01d___2367584017", "07269cdf84o1cn016___2367584017"]>, []}], names: MapSet.new([:delete_all])}
    
        # 2
        :delete
    
        # 3
        nil
    
        # 4
        []
    
    Attempted function clauses (showing 3 out of 3):
    
        def delete(multi, name, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset, opts)
        def delete(multi, name, %_{} = struct, opts) 
        def delete(multi, name, fun, opts) when is_function(fun, 1)
    
    (ecto 3.9.1) lib/ecto/multi.ex:388: Ecto.Multi.delete/4
    (mirror 0.1.0) lib/mirror/imports.ex:497: Mirror.Imports.import_product/3
    (elixir 1.14.1) lib/enum.ex:1658: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (mirror 0.1.0) lib/mirror/imports.ex:467: Mirror.Imports.extract_csv/1
    mirror_a.exs:14: (file)
    (elixir 1.14.1) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:347: anonymous fn/5 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
** (CompileError)  compile error
    (iex 1.14.1) lib/iex/helpers.ex:204: IEx.Helpers.c/2
```

How to avoid error when  `Repo.get_by(Mirror.Imports.Product, num_id: num_id)` return nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Ecto.Multi.delete/4` call fails because it expects an `Ecto.Schema.t()` struct or a changeset. You can use `delete_all/4` with a query. In that case your `nil` example would be  a query returning zero rows, which is fine.

```
  Ecto.Multi.new()
- |> Ecto.Multi.delete(:product, Repo.get_by(Mirror.Imports.Product, num_id: num_id))
+ |> Ecto.Multi.delete_all(:product, from(p in Mirror.Imports.Product, where: p.num_id == ^num_id))
```

Also keep in mind that `Ecto.Multi` is composable, and you can conditionally add operations, for example:

```
Ecto.Multi.new()
|> Ecto.Multi.delete_all(:foo, foo_query)
|> Ecto.Multi.delete_all(:bar, bar_query)
|> maybe_delete_record(id)

# ...

def maybe_delete_record(multi, id) do
  if record = Repo.get_by(Mirror.Imports.Product, num_id: num_id) do
    Ecto.Multi.delete_all(multi, :baz, record)
  else
    multi
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Both methods are workable. `limit: 1` is not allowed in the `delete_all` function's query clause.